# How to set timeout in recvmmsg()?

Tags: c

I build a simple application using c that used `recvmmsg()`, and the fifth parameter passed is timeout of `type struct timespec`. I set timeout to 5 seconds, but it's not working, it gets blocking infinity.

The code is as the following:

```
struct timespec timeout;

timeout.tv_sec =  5;
timeout.tv_nsec = 0;

result = recvmmsg(fd, datagrams, BATCH_SIZE, 0, &timeout);
```

Comment: There's a suggestion of a possible bug here that might be relevant: http://lists.openwall.net/netdev/2012/12/23/30

Comment: @Vicky: that's about right--similar to the link in my answer.  However it's not clear that anyone is going to change the behavior--more likely it will be considered a documentation bug, the man page will be updated, and the near-useless timeout parameter will simply not be used by most applications.

Comment: there is another solution in tha above link using select:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713438/how-to-add-delay-to-sento-and-recvfrom-in-udp-client-server-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative, you could use `setsockopt` with `SO_RCVTIMEO` option to set a timeout on the socket. This will affect all read operations performed on it.

Answer (score 5):

See here: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.man/3440

Basically the timeout parameter specifies a maximum amount of time to wait for more messages, but the underlying receive operation is still blocking.  So if you set a timeout of 5 seconds and receive one message every second, it will stop after receiving (about) 5 messages even if there is space in the buffers for more.  What it will not do is return after 5 seconds if there is no data coming at all.  For that you should use one of the usual mechanisms, like select() or epoll() with a timeout, or busy waiting, etc.

Comment: I can not really imagine a usecase where this is useful and intended.

Comment: From this answer's link, I found a quote to be very illustrative "recvmmsg() has an explicit timeout parameter but it doesn't look like it
works properly and the documentation doesn't mention how it is supposed to interact with SO_RCVTIMEO." This was helpful because it explains why you MUST set the socket's `SO_RCVTIMEO` parameter if you want the `recvmmsg()` timeout parameter to not block indefinitely. (My recvmmsg test code (from `man recvmmsg`) blocks indefinitely with a timeout of 1 second. If you set the SO_RCVTIMEO of the socket, then it doesn't block indefinitely.)

Answer (score 0):

There is bug in recvmmsg implementation:

- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75371
- http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.man/5677

Notice, `pselect` allow you to check if data is available. However, it does not guarantee `recvmmsg` will not wait forever. Therefore, don't use this method.

I suggest you to use `SO_RCVTIMEO` in add of `timeout` parameter of recvmmsg. recvmmsg will exit if no data was received since `SO_RCVTIMEO` or after `timeout`. In worst case, recvmmsg will exit after `timeout` + `SO_RCVTIMEO` (case where data is received just before end of `timeout` and no data arrive any more).