# Select() not working

Tags: c, sockets, unix, time, timeout

I need to implement a server code that receives a length of the expression and is going to receive it from the client, and it should wait up to 500 milliseconds, as noted below:

"*When the server receives the length message it will wait up to 500 milliseconds for that number of bytes to be sent.*"

The program consist of a simple UDP server-client program where the client sends an expression and the server processes it. I'm using `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` to send data between client/server respectively. 
This code is supposed to run on unix machines. I saw a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713438/how-to-add-delay-to-sento-and-recvfrom-in-udp-client-server-in-c) that had the same problem, and it was solved, but not for me. I've changed the code to be more similar as the recvfrom() system call, however it still doesn't work. Can somebody guess why it's not working?

```
ssize_t timeout_recvfrom(int sock, void *restrict buf, size_t length, int flags,
                         struct sockaddr_in *restrict connection, socklen_t *restrict len, float timeout){
fd_set socks;
    struct timeval t;
    FD_ZERO(&socks);
    FD_SET(sock, &socks);
    t.tv_sec = timeout;
    int aux = select(sock + 1, &socks, NULL, NULL, &t);
    long recvlen = recvfrom(sock, buf, length, 0, (struct sockaddr *) connection, len);
    if (aux && recvlen != -1) {
        return recvlen;
    }
    else {
        printf("select value: %d and recvlen: %lu\n",aux,recvlen);
        perror("cannot select()");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The server calls this function this way:

```
//recvlen = recvfrom(fd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, 0, NULL, 0);
recvlen = timeout_recvfrom(fd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, 0, NULL, 0, 0.5);
```

The commented version works, the other doesn't, it outputs:

```
select value: 0 and recvlen: 5
cannot select(): Undefined error: 0
Received 0 bytes
Received message: ""

Invalid term: `(null)'
```

`recvlen()` is supposed to have a 5 value, and I guess `aux` shouldn't be 0.

Comment: Your call to select returned 0, which means that the timeout expired. You don't initialize the microseconds part of the timeout and since you call the function with 0.5 as the timeout, the seconds part of the seconds part gets initialized to 0 (the microseconds part is probably garbage).

Comment: Don't `printf()` between the error-producing function call and `perror()`.

Comment: Don't breathe between the error-producing function call and perror()

Comment: Can't believe I was so clueless, thanks! And why shouldn't I `printf()` between the error-production function call and `perror()`? Bad programming habit?

Comment: You could miss the error from the function that produced it.  perror prints value of errno, which can change in an instant.

Comment: @WilliamStudart *Can't believe I was so clueless, thanks! And why shouldn't I `printf()` between the error-production function call and `perror()`?*  `printf()` is likely to munge the value of `errno`.

Comment: One minor point:  the timeval struct contains `long tv_sec, tv_usec`, but you are using a `float` to initialize, and you are only initializing one of them.   Consider changing the `type` of the last argument in the prototype to be long, or at least one of the `int` types. and consider initializing both members: `struct timeval timeout = {(long)timeout, 0};`  (cast assumes `timeout` is still `float`)

Comment: @AndrewHenle, according to the specification, `printf` does not change errno.

Comment: @SergeyA *according to the specification, `printf` does not change `errno.`*  That means the exact opposite of what you think it means.  Per **7.5 Errors `<errno.h>`** of the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf): *The value of
`errno`
may be set to nonzero by a library function call
whether or not there is an error,  provided the use of
`errno`
is not documented in the
description of the function in this International Standard.*

Comment: @ryyker this is not a minor point, this is the point! timeval not correctly initialized, and float value wrongly used to set an integer type. OP: You also should not try  to call receive if select fails... Your code logic is broken.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I fixed the type value, however I still don't  fully understand the `select()` logic. But at least I'm not as clueless as before. Thanks!

Comment: `select` is able to wait on many different channels to read and or write. `select` returns the number of channels on which you can do the operations you declared to be interested in. If the value is 0 (it seems to be your case), this means that no operation can be done... So first have a look at the return value of select, and if and only if this value is positive, then decode the set to determine on which channel something has to be done. But I would suggest you to use the timeout option on the socket, no use select in your case (you have only one channel!).

Comment: the posted code produces 4 warnings (compiled with gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -std=gnu99 )   To me, the first priority would be to produce a clean compile, then examine the actual execution.

Comment: this is the prototype for recvfrom() `ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
                        struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);`  That is NOT what the posted code is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to select returned 0, which means that the timeout expired. You don't initialize the microseconds part of the timeout and since you call the function with 0.5 as the timeout, the seconds part of the seconds part gets initialized to 0 (the microseconds part is probably garbage). – Art